# how to access django bash in portainer?

Tags: django, docker, portainer

I am able to access the django docker using the following in the cloud console

```
docker exec -it backend bash
```

How can I do the equivalent in Portainer GUI?

[image]

It is just stuck in

> Exec into container as default user using command bash

Comment: Have you tried with `/bin/bash` instead of `bash`? (see https://docs.portainer.io/v/ce-2.11/user/docker/containers/console)

Comment: @mtzd yes, that is the screenshot up in the question, no?

Comment: https://github.com/portainer/portainer/issues/3940 seems like this is happening to some other people recently since version 2.11.1. Could you check which Portainer version you're using? Maybe changing to a previous version solves it for you.